# Using java.net.http.HttpClient, how to bind to specific interface (for outgoing connections)?

Tags: java, http, java-11, java-http-client

How is it possible to bind to specific interface when using `java.net.http.HttpClient` (Java 11)?

When I was using Apache HttpClient, it was `setLocalAddress` method.

Comment: Outside of the crude controls here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html (IPv4 vs IPv6), it isn't clear this is possible.

Comment: If you have a working solution for Apache HttpClient why do you want to change it?

Comment: You're right that I can use current solution with Apache HttpClient and yes, I'm using it. But I wanted to switch to "native" Java 11 HTTP client and get rid of Apache HttpClient. Unfortunately it isn't possible.

Comment: AFAIK the native HTTP client was based on the Apache one. If you think some functionality is missing, consider bringing it up on the `net-dev@openjdk.java.net` mailing list.

Comment: You could set https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/Socket.html#setSocketImplFactory(java.net.SocketImplFactory) but it's a terrible solution

Comment: From what I have read here on SO the Java 11 HttpClient is IMHO not yet ready for production. Too many features missing or not fully working. Give it another year or two and it may be useful.

Comment: I have logged https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8218757

Comment: @Xdg Can I please ask why you need such a feature? Is it to support routing on a multi-homed machine? Why can the routing table not be used to determine the outbound interface to use?

Comment: Just use routing is frequest advice. But when you have one server with multiple IP addresses, where each of them has another public IP and you want to be seen with one of these addresses, bind application to specific interface (IP) is the answer.

Comment: @Xdg An API point to support such functionality similar to _builder.setLocalAddress(InetAddress)_ would result in selecting both the outbound interface to use ( as you would expect ), and also the IP protocol version ( IPv4 or IPv6 ). The latter seems less desirable, more of an unintended consequence.

Answer (score -1):

JDK 19 [adds](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8209137) `java.net.http.HttpClient.Builder#localAddress` method.